# Does Amazon S3 have a connection pool?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I ever used the code

```
public static AmazonS3Client s3 = null;
...
BasicAWSCredentials c = new BasicAWSCredentials("absadgwslkjlsdjgflwa");
s3 =  new AmazonS3Client(c);
```

Only one instance s3 is created while dozens of threads will upload images by s3.putObject(). In the dump info, I could see that one thread would lock the only instance s3 while the others were waiting.

So I think maybe it will be faster if I use the code below:

```
BasicAWSCredentials c = new BasicAWSCredentials("absadgwslkjlsdjgflwa");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    amazonS3[i] = new AmazonS3Client(c);
```

Everytime the system will get a random s3 instance and then upload the image.

```
private static AmazonS3 getS3(){
    int i = (int)(Math.random() * 10); 
    return amazonS3[i];
}
```

But it seems that the system slow down. Why that happened? 
Maybe the only instance s3 has already used connection pool? I am confused.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Each client in the AWS SDK for Java (including the Amazon S3 client) currently maintains it's own HTTP connection pool.  You can tune the maximum size of the HTTP connection pool through [the ClientConfiguration class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html) that can be passed into client object constructors.

We recommend sharing client objects, because of the expense and overhead of having too many HTTP connection pools that aren't being utilized effectively.  You should see better performance when you share client objects across threads like this.

Comment: for the less literate among us... are you saying Mark_H **should not** make an array of S3 clients? Are you suggesting he should use a single S3 client and pass it to different threads?

Comment: You referring to the setMaxConnections method here, I presume?

Comment: @mmcrae - that's correct.  reuse client objects across threads for more efficient resource usage (i.e. so you're sharing a single connection pool)

Comment: @rogerdpack - yup, the [max connections property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setMaxConnections(int)) controls the size of the connection pool for each client.

Comment: somewhat unrelated, in the hadoop world, the number of connections to s3 can be easily tuned with fs.s3a.connection.maximum if you're using s3a in hadoop 2.7+ (and possibly 2.6 although I can't be sure)

Comment: how can we set the max connection in node.js

Comment: is there anything like connection pool in aws-sdk for node.js

Comment: How can I share the S3Client if each thread has different credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Copy and run example

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration().withMaxErrorRetry(10).withMaxConnections(350);
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for AWS SDK V2:

1. Add the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client'
```

2. S3Client use ApacheHttpClient by default. So override the following configuration:

```
var config = ApacheHttpClient.builder().maxConnections(100);
return S3Client.builder().httpClientBuilder(config).build();
```

More details are described in [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration-apache.html)