# Rekognition client keeps rebuilding on each request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rekognition

I am using AWS Rekognition to build an application and I have realized that every time i make a request to the service a connection to aws keep being reestablished which is slowing down performance. Is there any way to make one single connection that persists throughout the session? My code can be seen below:

```
private static final AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = RekognitionUtil.setupRekognitionClient();

private static AWSCredentialsProvider setupCredentials(String accessKey, String secretKey) {

    AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
        @Override
        public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
            return new AWSCredentials() {
                @Override
                public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                    LOG.info("Access key: "  + ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_ACCESS_KEY,accessKey));
                    return ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_ACCESS_KEY,accessKey);
                }

                @Override
                public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                    LOG.info("Secret key: "  + ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_SECRET_KEY,secretKey));
                    return ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_SECRET_KEY,secretKey);
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void refresh() {

        }
    };

    return provider;

}


private static AmazonRekognition setupRekognitionClient() {

    AWSCredentialsProvider provider = setupCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");

    return AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider).withRegion(ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_REGION,"xxx")).build();

}

  private static AWSCredentialsProvider setupCredentials(String accessKey, String secretKey) {

    AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
        @Override
        public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
            return new AWSCredentials() {
                @Override
                public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                    LOG.info("Access key: "  + ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_ACCESS_KEY,accessKey));
                    return ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_ACCESS_KEY,accessKey);
                }

                @Override
                public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                    LOG.info("Secret key: "  + ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_SECRET_KEY,secretKey));
                    return ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_SECRET_KEY,secretKey);
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void refresh() {

        }
    };

    return provider;

}


private static AmazonRekognition setupRekognitionClient() {

    AWSCredentialsProvider provider = setupCredentials("xxxx", "xxx");

    return AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider).withRegion(ConfigUtil.getString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REKOGNITION_REGION,"xxx")).build();

}




 public static String searchCollectionByFace(String collectionId, ByteBuffer sourceByteBuffer) throws Exception {

    LOG.info("Searching face collection by face...");

    String faceId = "";

    try {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Get an image object from S3 bucket.
        Image image = new Image().withBytes(sourceByteBuffer);

        // Search collection for faces similar to the largest face in the image.
        SearchFacesByImageRequest searchFacesByImageRequest = new SearchFacesByImageRequest().withCollectionId(collectionId).withImage(image).withFaceMatchThreshold(70F).withMaxFaces(2);

        SearchFacesByImageResult searchFacesByImageResult = rekognitionClient.searchFacesByImage(searchFacesByImageRequest);

        List<FaceMatch> faceImageMatches = searchFacesByImageResult.getFaceMatches();

        for (FaceMatch face : faceImageMatches) {
            LOG.info(face.getFace().getFaceId());
            if(face.getFace().getConfidence() > SIMILARITY_LIMIT){
                faceId = face.getFace().getFaceId();
            }
        }

        return faceId;

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        LOG.error("Error has occurred searching for face", ex);
        throw new Exception();

    }

}
```

Comment: The SDK has pre-configured defaults for things like max connections. You can modify some of the behavior here, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/section-client-configuration.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354966/does-amazon-s3-have-a-connection-pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fine tune:

- [Max connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#withMaxConnections-int-)
- [Max connection idle time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#withConnectionMaxIdleMillis-long-)

in the client configuration you [pass to the client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#withClientConfiguration-com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration-).